# The Peter-Weyl Theorem and extensions of finite-dimensional representations

Tags: representation-theory

In *L-groups, projective representations, and the Langlands classification*, by Adams and Vogan, it is stated that a standard consequence of the Peter-Weyl Theorem is the following.

If $G$ is a compact group and $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$, then every finite-dimensional representation of $H$ has an extension to a finite-dimensional representation of $G$. (See Scholium 3.20.)

I have not seen this mentioned in any other texts and do not see how it follows from the Peter-Weyl Theorem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of *extension to a finite-dimensional representation of $G$*?

Comment: If $\rho:H\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $H$, then an extension of $\rho$ to $G$ is a representation $\pi:G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ such that $\pi$ restricts to $\rho$ on $H$.

Comment: Well, what about the one-dimensional representation of a circle group given by $e^{2 \pi i \theta} \mapsto e^{4 \pi i \theta}$? Scholium 3.20 of the cited paper implies this extends to a one-dimensional representation of $SU(2)$ on which the maximal torus $T=S^1$ acts by the given character? Suspicious!

Comment: (In case my comment wasn't explicit enough: it's not true that every finite dimensional representation of the maximal torus in $SU(2)$ extends in your sense. In fact, only the trivial representation does. I haven´t looked at the cited source, but perhaps you are misinterpreting it?)